# AWS EC2 current capacity monitoring in a given region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Recently, I am constantly rejected when trying to start p3/p4 instances on AWS EC2 with the "insufficient capacity" error. Is there an easy way or a tool to determine what's the current capacity in a given region? I am aware of Terraform, but I'd rather use something working more or less out of the box.

[image]

Comment: Did you try changing AZ?

Comment: @Marcin yes, but the requested instance was not supported in the different AZ

Comment: If this is really pressing issue, you should consider getting Capacity Reservation or Reserved Instances. Or maybe use different region.

Comment: Which Region and AZ are you using? Is it failing for _every_ P3/P4 instance type?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein us-east-2. I've tried p4, p3.8 and p3.16. The last two also with us-east-1 (p4 is not available there).

Comment: Additionally, p3.2xlarge is starting in us-east-2 (but that's too small for my needs).

Comment: I just now launched a `p2.8xlarge` in `us-east-2c` (which for me maps to `use2-az3`). When launching a `use2-az3`I got the message `We currently do not have sufficient p3.16xlarge capacity in zones with support for 'gp2' volumes.` When I changed to a gp3 volume it said `We currently do not have sufficient p3.16xlarge capacity in zones with support for 'gp2, gp3' volumes. Our system will be working on provisioning additional capacity.` However, I _could_ launch a `p3.8xlarge`.